# Pandas - select top N < L most frequent categories for multiple columns and join resulting vectors

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas I have separated my data by type and I need to summarize the frequency of the categorical data. I need to get all levels up to 50 levels.

Right now I have something like this (example data follows):

```
# Libraries
import numpy    as     np
import pandas   as     pd

# Categorical variables
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low  = 0, 
                                    high = 1000000, 
                                    size = (1000, 2)),
                       columns=['CASE_NUMBER', 'CLIENT_ID'])
df['CASE_NUMBER'] = df['CASE_NUMBER'].apply(str)
df['CLIENT_ID']   = df['CLIENT_ID'].apply(str)


df['PRODUCTCATEGORY']       = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(1000, 1))
df['PRODUCTTYPE']           = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(1000, 1))
df['PRODUCTTYPE']           = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(1000, 1))
df['PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DESC'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(1000, 1))
df['PRODUCT_DESC']          = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(1000, 1))

df.loc[df['PRODUCTCATEGORY'] == 0 , 'PRODUCTCATEGORY']             = "AC2"
df.loc[df['PRODUCTCATEGORY'] == 1 , 'PRODUCTCATEGORY']             = "AC1"
df.loc[df['PRODUCTTYPE'] == 0 , 'PRODUCTTYPE']                     = "AT2"
df.loc[df['PRODUCTTYPE'] == 1 , 'PRODUCTTYPE']                     = "AT1"
df.loc[df['PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DESC'] == 0 , 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DESC'] = "Revocable"
df.loc[df['PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DESC'] == 1 , 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DESC'] = "Irrevocable"
df.loc[df['PRODUCT_DESC'] == 0 , 'PRODUCT_DESC']                   = "Immediate"
df.loc[df['PRODUCT_DESC'] == 1 , 'PRODUCT_DESC']                   = ""
```

I made some very ugly way attempts that started something like what's below, but asides from being verbose it is slow and also adds unnecessary rows if the max number of levels in all columns is < 50:

```
e = df.describe()

table2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Variable Name': e.columns,
    })

for n in e.columns:
    for i in range(50):
        grouped = df.groupby([n]).size().reset_index()
        grouped = grouped.sort_values(0, ascending=False)
        table2 = pd.concat([table2, grouped], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Here is an example of what I'm ultimately going for (note: the counts are made up numbers that do not really correspond the the above data). You do not have to handle `Variable Name` and `Percent` (but bonus points for you if you do!):

[image]

Comment: ""I need to summarize the frequency of the categorical data."" <- maybe elaborate this sentence with an example?

Comment: @Hack-R the closest I can think of what I think you're after is probably `df.melt().groupby(['variable', 'value']).size()` right now... Is that close at all?

Comment: Not at desk right now but you could just do.. 
  ".to_frame(name='count')" for that

Comment: @Hack-R I'm okay. Sounds like you've worked out a potentially more thorough answer yourself - feel free to self-answer so others can benefit though.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the solution was in a comment from @JonClements:

```
table2 = df.melt().groupby(['variable', 'value']).size()
```

From there I just added some logic to truncate and transform the results:

```
table2 = table2.to_frame(name='Count')
table2 = table2.reset_index(inplace=False)
table2['Percent'] = table2['Count'] / len(df.index)

for v in table2['variable'].unique():    
    tmp    = table2[table2.variable.str.contains(v) == True]
    table2 = table2[table2.variable.str.contains(v) == False]
    if tmp.shape[0] > 50:
        tmp0 = tmp.iloc[:50,]
        tmp1 = pd.DataFrame([{'variable':v,
                            'value': 'Other',
                            'Count':tmp.shape[0]-50,
                            'Percent':sum(tmp0['Percent'])
                             }])
        tmp = tmp0.append(tmp1)
    table2 = table2.append(tmp)

print(table2)
```

Comment: Back at desk - think you're still doing a bit too much work here... what about: `counts = df.melt().groupby(['variable', 'value']).size().groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(50).to_frame(name='Count')` - which'll give you the top 50 value counts per variable? Then assign your percentage... `counts['Percentage'] = counts['Count'] / len(df)` ? (or similar)

Comment: @JonClements That's awesome! It should work. I didn't know about `nlargest`. I will test it out and update my answer accordingly.